# Efficient Background service for tracking user location

Tags: android, service, geolocation, batterylevel

I am developing a small android application in which I want to have Geolocation functionality.
What I want to code is one service which gives the updated location of a user whether they are using my application or not.

I know that if I am continuously checking the user's location it will drain the battery of the  device, so I want good solution for that. For example, to give me updates every 5 or 10 minutes. I have read about this question a lot but I wanted to get one good solution.

I read [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) and it's a good solution if the user is using my application but if the user not using my application then what should I do? How do I solve this challenge?

Answer (score 10):

Previously i have developed such kind of application. with respect to your requirement, you will be require following APIs from Android.

- [Location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513569/996493) ( for Lat-lon information )
- [AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/996493) ( to schedule an event to fetch lat-lon details on regular basis & upload data to remote server )
- Http ( an API to send lat-lon details to remote server )
- Android Service ( will allow to work in background )
- BroadcastReceiver ( additional , if you wan to start your application automatically on device boot )

Comment: Hye lucifer thank you for help. I will try this and let you know if having problem